# C# Test running configuration(*.runsettings)

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2015, mstest

By default Visual studio will run tests in 1 thread. I want to run it in parallel. I have test.runsettings file with code below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RunSettings>
      <RunConfiguration>
        <MaxCpuCount>4</MaxCpuCount>
      </RunConfiguration>
    </RunSettings>
```

When I rebuild solution or run the tests I'm getting the error below in OUTPUT window:

```
Invalid settings 'RunConfiguration'. Unexpected XmlElement: 'MaxCpuCount'.
```

I copy pasted the code for test.runsettings from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) doc and selected this file from VS Test menu.

I'm using Visual studio 2015.

**Problem is solved.** It will work on VS 2015 update 1 and +.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `Test` project in VS 2015 or newer according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and creating a `test.runsettings` file

adding your content to this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <MaxCpuCount>4</MaxCpuCount>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

And adding it to the testsettings, works fine for me.
Have a look at the MSDN-Documentation. You might have done something wrong.

**EDIT:**

You may have updates for your VS? if not, maybe something wrong with the solution or with your VS.

As last option, reinstall VS.

Comment: *.runsettings is not the name of file, file name is settings.runsettings

Comment: Adding your mentioned code to testsettings file will not work, because testsettings format is different than runsettings

Comment: @Jamaxack not adding it to the testsettings file, adding it inside visual studio -> On the Test menu, choose Test Settings, Select Test Settings File -> select test.runsettings or whatever it's called. This worked for me, i tested it.

Comment: Yes, I selected test.runsettings from VS and there is error that I mentioned in question

Comment: It is working in another machine, but I bon't know why it is not working in my machine

Comment: @Jamaxack you _may_ have updates for your VS? if not, maybe something wrong with the solution or with your VS. At last option reinstall VS. Furthermore i've no more ideas.

Comment: Thanks! The issue was on my VS version, now I'm updating my VS hope it  will work.

Comment: @Jamaxack do you mind giving +1 as the solution is in the comments. I'll update the answer too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118410/discussion-between-jamaxack-and-m-schena).

Answer (score 1):

Unloading and reloading the test project worked for me.